# flink idle source slow to process

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have two Kafka topics, A and B.

On occasion both topics can be idle, however, when topic B or A has new data, it can take a few minutes for the flink application to process (after being idle).

The application is configured to use event time, using forMonotonousTimestamps.

The job is structured like so:

- KafkaSource
- ProcessFunction
- KeyBy
- connect the two streams
- CoProcessFunction

The ProcessFunction immediately picks up data from the Kafka topic (even after it is idle) and likewise for the KeyBy.

However neither the process1 or process2 of the CoProcessFunction get triggered quickly, I see a delay of around 3 minutes before they are, why is this?

Performance is otherwise very good when both topics have data continuously pushed to them.

I have also tried to implement my own WatermarkGenerator, like so

```
    @Override
    public void onEvent(T event, long eventTimestamp, WatermarkOutput output) {
        // don't need to do anything because we work on processing time
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeriodicEmit(WatermarkOutput output) {
        output.emitWatermark(new Watermark(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
```

I can see the `onPeriodicEmit` function does emit every 5 seconds, but this doesn't solve my problem, and looking at the flink webui, the watermark does not progress.

Using Flink 1.14

Comment: Are you using FlinkKafkaConsumer or KafkaSource?

Comment: @MartijnVisser KafkaSource

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that there's an issue with the idleness detection:

```
The Kafka Source does not go automatically in an idle state if 
the parallelism is higher than the number of partitions. 
You will either need to lower the parallelism 
or add an idle timeout to the watermark strategy. 
If no records flow in a partition of a stream for that amount of time,
then that partition is considered “idle” and 
will not hold back the progress of watermarks in downstream operators.
```

See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#idleness for more details and how to assign a `WatermarkStrategy#withIdleness` to resolve this.

Comment: Is the WatermarkGenerator (in my question), not enough?

Comment: No, because you are only defining how watermarks should be generated, not how idle sources should be treated.